# Objects field is set with wrong default value in Django

Tags: python, django, oop, django-rest-framework

I modified a default value in an objects' field but it has not been taken in account.
I have deleted the database, migrations files and pycaches.

In the current configuration shouldn't plateforme.name be set with 'Plateforme_Test_1' ?
Because instead, I have the old default value 'default_plateforme'.

I am talking about plateforme objects, not environnement objects.

Thank you for your help.

PS: Here is the snippet:

```py
class Plateforme(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = 'Plateforme_Test_1')
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Environnement(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = 'default_module')
    plateforme = models.ForeignKey('homepage.Plateforme', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Environnement', null = True)
    plateforme_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = 'default_plateforme')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      
        if self.name == 'M42048':
             self.name = 'Env'

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

PS 2:
Here is i screenshot of the api on the plateforme page:
[image]

Comment: Well why is there a `plateforme_name` in your `Environment`?

Comment: plateforme_name is meant to be set based on Plateforme.name in:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

It is just for more conveniance

Comment: But if later the `Plateforme` changes, the environments for that `Platforme` will not adapt...

Comment: Yes but it is not the problem 

Context:
I missing data for presenting my POC so I wanted some fake data.

As such I wanted to generate multiple Plateformes, Env, etc... By providing different default values once at the time.

However, since I changed the default value for plateforme.name, it kept its old value.

Moreover on the coding I am running right now, plateforme_name is just a field with no relation to plateforme.name....